# Neo4j cypher query on relationship property return relative results

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have nodes A and B and a relationship R from A to B. R has a property date_created. Is it possible to construct a Neo4j query that matches a specific A and returns the related (through R) B nodes with, say, the 10 highest values of date_created?

I think it would be straightforward if I wanted to return the B nodes that had a date_created property on R of greater than some specific date, but not sure if I can do the kind of relative query I want to do?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't listing any labels, so I'll assume that you have a 'Object' label:

```
MATCH (a:Object)-[:r]->(b:Object)
WHERE a.some_property = {some_value}
RETURN b
ORDER BY r.date_created DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thank you, Brian. Much appreciated. It's more like regular SQL than I expected!